# reassigning account executives - apex class

Tags: apex, batch, exception

I am trying to reassign Account executives depending on the requested date of open cancellation opportunities. If the requested date is 90 days later than today, I want the open cancellation opportunity to be reassigned to Account Executive in an apex class.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String sQuery;
    sQuery = 'SELECT Id,
                    Account.AccountExecutive__c,
                    OwnerId
              FROM Opportunity
              WHERE StageName NOT IN (\'Closed Won\',\'Closed Lost\' )
                AND Days_to_Request_Date__c = 90
                AND RecordTypeId = rtOpportunityCancellation';
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sQuery = 'SELECT Id,
                         Account.AccountExecutive__c,
                         OwnerId
                  FROM Opportunity
                  WHERE StageName NOT IN (\'Closed Won\',\'Closed Lost\' )
                  AND Days_to_Request_Date__c = 90
                  AND RecordTypeId = rtOpportunityCancellation limit 1';
    }
    return Database.getQueryLocator(sQuery);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
    list<Opportunity> opportunities = (List<Opportunity>) scope;
    Opportunity opp = opportunities[0];
    try {
        // c.Reevaluate__c = true;
        opp.Account.AccountExecutive__c = opp.OwnerId ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errMessage += '<br/>' + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

However, when I run the test, i am getting the following error :

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Please select a "why cancelled" value.: [Why_Cancelled__c]
>   Class.reassign_AccExecutiveTest.reassign_AccExecutiveTest: line 37, column 1

Any ideas about what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from a custom validation rule.

Probably at some point someone has added a rule which requires a "why cancelled" value to be entered on Opportunities. You have existing data which fails this validation. The validation is being triggered by your batch job trying to make an edit to the Opportunity records in question.

If you look at the criteria for the validation, you should be able to write some SOQL to find the row(s) that are causing this problem. You can resolve it either by fixing the rows or by fixing the rule.